# How to improve the way I handle greping in this script

Tags: optimization, bash, linux

What my script does is:

1. Append data to a file on a continuous basis.
2. If an error pattern is observed, then do something.

I need feedback on the way I am grepping for patterns in the continuously appended file. For grep, I am creating a pattern file first and then using it with -f option to grep. Can I do this better? Any other better way I can write my over all logic.

Here's my script

```
#!/bin/bash
# List of error patterns to look for. Add more patterns to this list
p1='pattern1'
p2='pattern2'
p3='pattern3'
p4='pattern4'

PATTERNFILE=~/patternfile
FILETOCHECK=~/filetocheck

captureFileToCheck()
{
   //appends data into filetocheck &

}
createPatternFile()
{

    for i in `seq 100` # hopefully 100 is all we will need
    do
        if [ ! "x$p{$i}" = "x" ]
        then
            echo $p{$i} >> $PATTERNFILE
        else
            break
        fi
    done
}

createPatternFile
captureFileToCheck

while [ 1 ]
do

    if grep -f $PATTERNFILE $FILETOCHECK
    then
        echo "something starting"

          #doSometing

        echo "something complete"

        break
    fi

done
```

Comment: Any specific issue you're having? Security? Efficiency? Accuracy? Complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another go at your function

```
patterns() {
cat <<EOF
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3
pattern4
EOF
}
```

However, the `$patternfile` is not a necessity. I would go with just

```
while :
do    
  grep -f <(patterns) $filetocheck && {
    echo found;
    break
  }
done
```

Comment: This is a good way to do it. I am concerned about portability!

Comment: Ignore my comment about portability. Arrays are ok since this is explicitly bash.

Answer (score 3):

[Use more quotes](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html), as the saying goes.

I find `while true` is more clear, but the idiomatic `while :` is also popular.

You might want to use an array for the patterns, then you can simply loop over it (`for pattern in "${patterns[@]}"`) instead of using `seq` and the `if` statement.

Uppercase variables are usually used for exports; that is, stuff which is relevant *outside* your script.

You should avoid cluttering `~`; use `tmp_dir="$(mktemp -d)"` instead.